# Regular black hole with an evanescent horizon

Tags: black-holes, singularities, research-level, hawking-radiation

I'm reading a great paper named [Geodesically Complete Black Holes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.11200) by R. Carballo, F. Filippo, S. Liberati and M. Visser about regular black holes and I'm trying to understand a particular situation. To put this into context, I'm interesting in the case named as **evanescent horizons** that supposes an existence of a set of defocusing points. This particular case is defined as:

> $(λ_0, R_0,\theta^{\text{in}}(\lambda_0)<0)$: The expansion $\theta^{\text{out}}$ vanishes and changes sign at a finite affine distance $\lambda=\lambda_0$ or, in terms of the radius, at a value $R_0 > 0$ of the radial coordinate along the congruence of outgoing radial null geodesics at $\lambda=\lambda_0$. On the other hand, the expansion of the
> intersecting ingoing radial null geodesics remains negative until (and including) $\lambda_0$, so that $\theta^{\text{out}}(\lambda_0)<0$

Where the congruence of outgoing radial null geodesics are all **stemming from trapped surfaces** (in $\lambda=0$) as said by the authors. So, they states that:

> There must exist $2k + 1$ (with $0 \leq k$) open intervals in the domain of $v(R_0)$ where the latter is bijective and the inverse function $R_0(v)$ exists, which must be either a
> strictly increasing or strictly decreasing function in $k + 1$ of these intervals, and either a strictly decreasing or strictly increasing function in the remaining $k$ intervals.

Before saying what is struggling me, one more result: they also proved that to every constant $v$ there **must** exist an even number of points $r$ such that $\theta^{\text{out}}$ vanishes.

The basic case happens when there's just $2$ points and its looks standard (the authors already used as an example as Figura 6 shows). My conclusion is that they consider just the red side, instead to consider all the left side, because we are considering only those points related to geodesicas leaving **from** trapped surfaces.
[image]

**QUESTION: I cannot see how we can have any case with more than $2$ points that $F(v,r)$ vanishes along $v$ in such manner that the above proposition holds.**

If someone can help me too see an example, or even knows any other references I'll appreciate very much.